# buffer becomes NULL after reindexing

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *color[] =
{
    /*0*/"red||bluegreen",
    /*1*/"blue",
    /*2*/"green",
         "\0"
};

int fun1(char * str1)
{
    int c = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(str1[c] == '|' && str1[c+1] == '|')
            return c;
        c++;    
    }
    return 0;    
}


1. int main()
2. {
3.  int ret=0, offset=0;
4.  ret = fun1(color[offset]);
5   offset += ret;
6   ret = fun1(color[offset]);

7   return 0;
   }
```

In the above code snippet in `main()` at line 6 the argument to `fun1()` is `color[offset] = NULL`
Why is `color[offset] = NULL` after the operation `offset += ret`. Please clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first call to `fun1` here  `ret = fun1(color[offset]);` returns `3` as `color[0][3]` and `color[0][4]` are both `|`.

Then you add `ret` to `offset` making it `3`.

In the next call to `fun1` you pass it `color[offset]` which is `color[3]` which is `"\0"`, note that this is **not** `NULL` its a string literal containing only the `nul` character.

To clarify:

```
char *str = NULL;  // str is null pointer.
char *str = 0;     // same as above.

char *str = "\0";  // str is pointer to an empty string literal.
char *str = "";    // same as above.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add to offset, it is going to advance by the number equal to ret. So, it advances 3 places, which brings it to an offset of 3, so `color[offset] = color[3] = "\0"`. When you then call fun1, it will loop forever because there are no `|` characters. This continues until something terrible and undefined happens.